# Coding for enterprise level wifi networks javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, wifi

I have done a wifi application using javascript or jquery. This application only supports personal WPA or WPA2 networks which is also the home level networks which has only password validation. Now my question is how can I write the coding for an enterprise level wifi networks where you have validations like username, identity, and password. So please someone give me suggestions or ideas.Thank u.

I have did the home level wifi application using javascript,jquery and cordova-plugin-wifiwizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create the web service which will be in enterprise and server, take example

You have to do ajax call from java-script or jquery(Restful type webservice I am using here)

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: " http://localhost:8080/service-name",
            data: JSON.stringify({}),
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            },

            success: function(data) {

                    *code*

             }


            },
            error: function(data, status, er) {

                alert("Something went wrong! Please contact your Administrator.");
            }
```

This will connect to your web-service which is in the server and that server will connect to your database, store  necessary information with table like password and username. The main thing in this you have to do all validation stuff in web-service(enterprise code). Read web services tutorial to achieve this https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/

Comment: @RSN Yes, Authentication will be done there itself, You will get response in json use it according to your application. And you should know json,web services and connection to server to hit the web services

Comment: k, thanks let me try and in my case im just scanning the networks around me so in the url tag what exact detail am I suppose to provide. Like the network details or its server details

Comment: fine, it takes time for me to understand these because the WPA2 personal wifi was easy to understand using the plugin wifiwizard and does the plugin support is needed for this enterprise wifi network

Comment: Did u converted to Json String with JSON.stringify({})

Comment: K, I have checked and whether the cordova hotspot plugin will support this enterprise level networks.

Comment: Yes it will support, that is the main reason to use of plugins in cordova

Comment: K, let me try that and if you got any idea about how to approach using that hotspot plugin please give me a suggestion. thnk u

Comment: I'm getting error from the program from cordova-plugin-hotspot sample. It says that the module starter is not defined.

Comment: Debug it chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: it says cordova.js not found and the module name was mispelled. Is that a link u gave in the above command and what it does or how can I use it

Comment: please have a look at my new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244163/cordova-plugin-hotspot-module-error-angularjs

Comment: Use that cordova.js script at end... in html

Comment: its not working still, please have a look at the function onDeviceReady on the link I provided in the above comment, If you avoid that angular.bootstrap then something works, again you will get cordova.js is not defined. Please have a look at the above link i provided in the command

Comment: can you find that error in the onDeviceReady function?

Comment: Give me the full file so that  I can try here or post it somewhere like fiddle,plunker

Comment: I spoke to the hotspot plugin hypery2k guy, he said that he is no more working on this hotspot sample because he too gets the same error. And the link which I provided in the above link, you will have the full program in there(index.html, app.js and controller.js)

Comment: lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js THIS IS missing in that

Comment: Try this http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/create-and-manage-hotspots-in-your-phonegap-app/

Comment: The  lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js is in the script tag there. It haven't got missed. And I have tried that website already and The problem is the commands which has that cordova.plugin.hotspot, this will be the actual error if you run it. It says that the cordova was not defined. If you fixed it please tell me what to change

Comment: For me cordova is okay, problem with that bundle it is showing

Comment: k, so how we gona fix it,@OhStack